# Regular expression and grep

Tags: linux, grep, expression

I want to find text in files by regular expression using grep.
This is the text I want to find, where is the white space before closing bracket:

```
{if sometexthere }
```

My command is:

```
grep -E -n "\{if[^\}]*[\s+]+\}" mydir/*
```

But it found lines where there is no white space before closing bracket, such as

```
{if sometexthere}
```

Comment: It also should find tabs, new lines \t\n

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
grep -E "\{if[^\}]*?\s+\}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have made the regex needlessly complex.  Try:

```
grep "{if[^}]*\s}$" filename
```